# How to run an Ansible task with become and the same $PATH?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, ansible

I want to run [this task](https://github.com/andreicristianpetcu/alaveteli_ansible/blob/27b5120c4f1c1092b0a7ad3ae0b1c737863598ed/restore.yml#L47-L56) but it fails since it does not find the `bundle` binary because the user I am running it with has a different $PATH in Ansible than when I just `sudo su - deploy`.

If I SSH into the box as root and then run 
`sudo su - deploy` and `echo 'whoami' $PATH` I get `deploy /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`.

But if I the same command as the `shell:` part of the ansible task I get `deploy /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`.

The `rbenv` part is set up in `/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh` but somehow it is not loaded if I run it with Ansible.

I found a wacky hack to prefix all my `shell:` params with `source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh` but it feels dirty :)

How can I fix this?

PS: I'm using Ansible 2.0.2.0 on my Fedora 23 and it talks to Ubuntu 14.04 servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bencane.com/2013/09/16/understanding-a-little-more-about-etcprofile-and-etcbashrc/

> The difference is simple, the /etc/profile is executed only for
>   interactive shells and the /etc/bashrc is executed for both
>   interactive and non-interactive shells. In fact in Ubuntu the
>   /etc/profile calls the /etc/bashrc directly.

So include your /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh in .bashrc or

> I found a wacky hack to prefix all my shell: params with source
>   /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh

Comment: I think you are on to something here. I did not mark it as a successful answer since it does not work but I think it is a interactive v.s. non-interactive shell.

I put source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh in both /home/deploy/.bashrc and in /etc/bash.bashrc. While it seems that it picks it up when I run in interactive mode, it is ignored in Ansible. I will troubleshoot this more and keep you posted if I fix it :) Thank you!